# Split string to array in nifi jolt

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am looking for the jolt specs to split the `treefield` string value to a list of JSON objects in below mentioned format.

Could someone help me with the jolt specs to convert the below mentioned input to the output

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2",
    "C": {
      "D": "x1",
      "E": {
        "treefield": "k1-value1#k2-value2"
      },
      "F": {
        "a": "x1",
        "x": {
          "y": 1
        }
      },
      "H": "x4"
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2",
    "C": {
      "D": "x1",
      "E": {
        "treefield": [
          {
            "paramid": "k1",
            "paramvalue": {
              "string": "value1"
            }
          },
          {
            "paramid": "k2",
            "paramvalue": {
              "string": "value2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "F": {
        "a": "x1",
        "x": {
          "y": 1
        }
      },
      "H": "x4"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Does treefield value always consist of two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can manage that problem. I was basing on: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/522

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "C": {
          "E": {
            "treefield": {
              "*#*": {
                "$(0,1)": "temp[]",
                "$(0,2)": "temp[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": {
        "*": {
          "*-*": {
            "$(0,1)": "[#3].paramid",
            "$(0,2)": "[#3].paramvalue.string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **modify-overwrite-beta** transformations successively along with `split` function in order to seperate the concerned string by `#` and `-` characters, and then use **shift** transformation to shape as desired such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "C": {
          "E": {
            "*": "=split('#',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "C": {
          "E": {
            "*": "=split('-',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "C": {
          "*": "&1.&",
          "E": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "0": "&4.&3.&2.[&1].paramid",
                "1": "&4.&3.&2.[&1].paramvalue.string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```